# There is no Network Manager in the panel for the second user

Tags: 10.10, network-manager

I have Ubuntu 10.10 and I have two users registered on it. Once User1 enters to the system and doesn't close his session and User2 enters to the system, User2 can't see Network Manager in his panel. So, he can not see list of available WiFi, etc.

How can I solve this bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a well known upstream bug that appears to be unfixable. It has been open for over two years. You can see [the bug report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/284596).

In the event that you are logged in second and you therefore do not have the nm-applet in your panel, you can run the following command to kill the currently running instance and then restart network manager for your login

```
sudo killall -9 nm-applet && nm-applet &
```

Comment: Is there any way to automate this in a shell script + setuid upon user switching? (I'd like users with no administrative permissions to have nm-applet as well..)

Comment: dr Hannibal Lecter: You probably could do something along these lines. I would suggest posting a new question, either here on on unix.stackexchange.com. You'll get better feedback than asking just me.

Answer (score 2):

Normally this means the second user isn't authorized to change NM settings.

- Make common connections available system-wide.
- Give the second user the authorizations required from the Users configuration screen.

Comment: What happens if I want to turn off the wifi?

Comment: @Bakhtiyor see my second point.

Comment: What authorizations are you talking about? Because I gave the authentication for connecting to wireless networks from the User Configuration.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor that ought to be sufficient...

Comment: But it is not sufficient. I still have the same problem.